# Java, how to using expression language in pure java

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, juel

I have a JavaEE web application, as it will be deployed to some kind of application servers such as weblogic websphere tomcat etc. so the EL api will be avaiable for me, but I don't need to care about what EL implementation is used.

I want to use EL in my java code, not jsp pages, to translate some simple expression to value constants, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ExpressionFactory ef = new ExpressionFactoryImpl();
        SimpleContext ec = new SimpleContext();
        ec.setVariable("value", ef.createValueExpression("0", String.class));
        ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(ec, "${value == \"1\" ? \"enabled\" : \"disabled\"}", String.class);
        System.out.println(ve.getValue(ec));
    }
```

however, in this example, I used JUEL library, so I need to access JUEL implementation classes. my question is how Can I do the same thing but just use classes in `javax.el` package ?

Do I need to implement my own `ELContext` and `VariableMapper` and other abstract classes ?

Comment: FYI: this is natively possible since EL 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) solve my problem, it's flexible and powerful!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to hack EL together with your code, I think in some cases that might be problemmatic.

There are quite a lot of libraries offering similar functionalities (known as *Template Engines*), try [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html) or [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_basics.html) for example. They are extremely easy to use and have quite a lot of options.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. Actually I need some kind fast and simple expression interpreter in Java. I never used any Template Engines, but it seems that they are not intended to be used as a expression interpreter? Whatever, I will check that two template engines you mentioned.